# jquery .is(":focus") returning false on ios webview

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, webview, focus

I was trying for hours to find why `$('#something').is(":focus")` within a function which got called `onInput` was returning false on an input field within an ios webview while i was typing in it.

If you know why i would appreciate knowing it too.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find out why but was able to detour by using pure javascript checking if the `document.activeElement.id == 'something'`.